# umi functions causing Application error: a client-side exception has occurred

Tags: metaplex, nft, nextjs

My website works fine locally but when deployed to Vercel, I get a client-side exception error. After checking other parts of the website, I've found the culprit to be in my UMI function code. I'm getting an error of:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

That I think might be coming from:

```
(candyMachine.itemsRedeemed === 500 as BigIntInput)
```

Not sure if that has to do with how the candymachine is fetched or if I'm using the BigIntInput wrong and need a different way to read if items redeemed is less than 500?

Here is my full code for the page. Like I mentioned earlier it will work fine on the local level. It's just not working in production.

```
import {
  some,
  generateSigner,
  transactionBuilder,
  publicKey,
  BigIntInput
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import {
  CandyMachine,
  fetchCandyMachine,
  mintV2
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine";
import { TokenStandard } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import { setComputeUnitLimit } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-toolbox";
import { CircularProgress, Container, } from "@mui/material";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from '../../styles/mint.module.css';
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import { mplCandyMachine } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine";
import { walletAdapterIdentity } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-signer-wallet-adapters';
import { WalletMultiButton } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";


const CarMint = () => {
  const wallet = useWallet();
  const [pageLoading, setPageLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [candyMachine, setCandyMachine] = useState<CandyMachine | undefined>();
  const [isUserMinting, setIsUserMinting] = useState(false);
  const owner = publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OWNER_WALLET as unknown as string);
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const umi = createUmi(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOLANA_RPC_HOST as unknown as string)
  .use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet))
  .use(mplCandyMachine());

  const getCandyMachine = async () => {
    setPageLoading(true);
    try {
      const cmPubkey = publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CANDY_MACHINE_CAR_ID as unknown as string);
      const candyMachine = await fetchCandyMachine(umi, cmPubkey);
      if (!candyMachine) throw new Error("No Candymachine at address");
      setCandyMachine(candyMachine);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Fetching CM Error", error);
      enqueueSnackbar(
        "Fetching CM Error: Check console logs for more details",
        {
          variant: "error",
          anchorOrigin: { vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" },
        }
      );
    }
  
    setPageLoading(false);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getCandyMachine();
  }, []);



  const getPayMintButtonContent = () => {
    if (!candyMachine) {
      return "Loading...";
    }

    if (isUserMinting) {
      return "Minting in progress..";
    } else if (candyMachine.itemsRedeemed === 500 as BigIntInput) {
      return "Sold out";
    } else {
      return <img
      style={{
        maxHeight: "75px",
      }}
      src="/images/freeby.png"
      alt="freeby"
    />;
    }
  };

  const payMintButtonClicked = async () => {
    setIsUserMinting(true);
    try {
      if (candyMachine?.publicKey) {
        const nftMint = generateSigner(umi);
    const freeMint = await transactionBuilder()
      .add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 800_000 }))
      .add(
        mintV2(umi, {
          candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
          nftMint,
          collectionMint: candyMachine.collectionMint,
          collectionUpdateAuthority: owner,
          group: some("fren"),
          mintArgs: {
            mintLimit: some({ id: 1 }),
            solPayment: some({ destination: owner }),
          },
          tokenStandard: TokenStandard.ProgrammableNonFungible,
        })
      )
      .sendAndConfirm(umi);
    
      console.log( "Mint Success!!!", freeMint )
      enqueueSnackbar(
        "Mint Success!!!",
        {
          variant: "success",
          anchorOrigin: { vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" },
        }
      );
      getCandyMachine();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Mint Error", error);
      enqueueSnackbar("Mint Error: Only one per customer, Pal!!!", {
        variant: "error",
        anchorOrigin: { vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" },
      });
    }
    setIsUserMinting(false);
  };



  return (
    <Container style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
    <Container maxWidth="xs" style={{ position: 'relative' }}> 
      <Paper
          style={{ padding: 24, background: '#3a434a', borderColor: '#ffd839', border: '3px solid #ffd839', borderRadius: 6 }}
        >
          {!wallet.connected ? (
              <div className={styles.connectButton}>
              <WalletMultiButton className="w-80 text-center mx-3">
              <img className="mt-10" src="/images/freeby.png"></img>
              </WalletMultiButton>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Grid
                container
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="center"
                wrap="nowrap"
              >
                {pageLoading ? (
            <CircularProgress />
            ) : (
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                  <Typography variant="h6" color="#ffd839" style={{
                      textAlign: "center", fontFamily: "Press Start 2P"
                    }}>
                    Redeemed
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography
                    variant="h6"
                    color="white"
                    style={{
                      fontWeight: "bold",
                      textAlign: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                    {`${candyMachine ? candyMachine.itemsRedeemed : "Loading.."}`}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
                )}
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                    <Typography 
                      variant="h6" 
                      color="#ffd839"
                      style={{ fontFamily: "Press Start 2p" }}
                      >
                        .
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography
                      variant="h6"
                      color="white"
                      style={{ fontFamily: "Press Start 2P" }}
                    >
                      /500
                    </Typography>
                  </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                    <Typography 
                      variant="h6" 
                      color="#ffd839"
                      style={{ fontFamily: "Press Start 2p" }}
                      >
                        Price USDC
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography
                      variant="h6"
                      color="white"
                      style={{ fontFamily: "Press Start 2P" }}
                    >
                      Free Fiddy
                    </Typography>
                  </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid
                container
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="center"
                wrap="nowrap"
              >
                <div className={styles.mintButton}>
                <Button onClick={async () => await payMintButtonClicked()} disabled={isUserMinting || candyMachine?.itemsRedeemed === 500 as BigIntInput}>
                  <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" style={{
                      fontSize: "16px",
                      fontWeight: "bold",
                      color: "white",
                      textAlign: "center",
                    }}>
                    { getPayMintButtonContent() }
                  </Typography>
                </Button>
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </>
          )}
        </Paper>
      </Container>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CarMint;
```

Answer (score 1):

When fetching a candy machine account, the type of `candyMachine.itemsRedeemed` will always be a `bigint`. Therefore:

```
(candyMachine.itemsRedeemed === 500 as BigIntInput)
```

is strictly comparing a `number` with a `bigint` and should always be false. You want'll to use this instead:

```
(candyMachine.itemsRedeemed === BigInt(500))
```

Perhaps this wrong condition is causing your code to wrongly access the `length` of an array somewhere. That being, said I'm not sure why this condition would pass locally.